# How to iterate/display form array in angular2 reactive forms?

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript, reactive

How to populate this JSON in my EditForm. I have EditForm, that I want to display my data inside Products, my ws get me this JSON. My data outside Products I can display in html. What is the problem?

This is my Json

```
{
   "StatusCode": 0,
"StatusMessage": "OK",
"StatusDescription": [
    {
        "Products": [
            {
                "p_product_id": "11E8218A54B30C89AE8800FF76874A59",
                "p_product_type_id": "11E7FC041F467AD4B09D00FF76874A59",
                "p_line_num": 233,
                "p_description": "test",
                "p_quantity": 4,
                "p_unit_price": 50,
                "p_subtotal": 120,
                "p_contract_filename": "567897"
            }
        ],
        "sale_item_id": "11E8219D916A69F6AE8800FF76874A59",
        "sale_id": "11E8218B9BA4F278AE8800FF76874A59",
        "client_id": "11E8218A57B28B0AAE8800FF76874A59",
        "salesman_id": "31000000000000000000000000000000",
        "sale_date": "2018-03-06T22:09:43.000Z",
        "notes": "testing",
        "subtotal": 80,
        "total": 50,
        "invoice_number": "28282",
        "invoice_date": "2018-03-06T21:57:41.000Z",
        "amount_paid": 32,
        "lastmoduserid": "31000000000000000000000000000000",
        "lasttodtttm": "2018-03-06T22:09:43.000Z"
    }
]
```

}

My ts code:

```
 this.sale.products.forEach(x => {
              (this.editSaleForm.get('products') as FormArray).push(new FormControl(x.products))
            })
```

html code:

```
 <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let sale of editSaleForm.get('products').value; let i = index">
    <td >{{p_product_type_id}}</td>
    <td>{{p_product_id}}</td>
    <td>{{p_unit_price}}</td>
    <td>{{p_quantity}} </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: `let sale of editSaleForm.get('products').value` are you trying to get `sale.value` for each sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to access them like `{{sale.p_product_type_id}}`

```
<tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let sale of editSaleForm.get('products').value; let i = index">
    <td >{{sale.p_product_type_id}}</td>
    <td>{{sale.p_product_id}}</td>
    <td>{{sale.p_unit_price}}</td>
    <td>{{sale.p_quantity}} </td>
  </tr>
```

You should be probably using an array of `FormGroup`s. And make the code something like:

```
this.sale.products.forEach(product => {
    (this.editSaleForm.get('products') as FormArray).push(this.createFormGroupForPoduct(product))
})

createFormGroupForProduct(product: Product): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
       p_line_num: new FormControl(product.p_line_num),
       p_description: new FormControl(product.p_description, [Validators.required]),
       ......
    })
}
```

So that you get the value of `FormArray` as an array of products `Product[]`

I don't know if there are other issues in your code.